# MouseUp and MouseDown Events in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, jquery

I have a simple html5/canvas and js-setup:

### HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" ></canvas>
```

### JS

```
var canvas = $("#canvas"),
    c = canvas[0].getContext("2d");

c.fillStyle = "gray";
c.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

$(document).mousedown(function() {
    console.log('down');
});
$(document).mouseup(function() {
    console.log('up');
});
```

What buffles me is that I am able to log events with `google chrome` like so

```
down
up
down
up
down 
down 
down 
down
up
down
down
down
```

meaning, I get consecutive down events. I think it is caused by the canvas element, because I am not able to reproduce this behavior without it.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SunnyRed/zcmaT/

### Update

I think it only happens, when the user clicks and drags, which might be the case in my scenario. Here is a simple clicking [demo](http://www.5plus5.com/files/privat/var/mouse_click_events_chrome.wmv). I can't reproduce it in Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I could replicate this is in your demo was that I either:

- started a click outside the page (in another iframe from JS fiddle) and then did the mouse up over the canvas.  Or
- start the click on the canvas and then release it outside the bounds of the page (such as over the page padding).

I believe this is the correct behaviour.

Comment: I can't tell exactly how to achieve it. I takes some clicking and possibly some simultaneous dragging, but I do not have to leave or enter the canvas. Sometimes it takes a while, other times it happens real quick. Any chance you might experience it as well?

Comment: Did you have a chance to take a second look?